# jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named default

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have tried every solution i could possible find, and nothing seemed to have worked.
it seems like my EntityManager is unable to find my Persistence provider.

hoping for some advice, and posisbly a solution.

Thanks!

**Error:**

```
jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named default
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:86)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
```

**pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="default">     
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>...</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="*******"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="*******"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.exclude_unlisted_classes" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**persistence.xml Location:**
`/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`

**Instantiation of EntityManager** (uses Jakarta.persistence)

```
 public static void hibernateSaving(Player player) {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();

        saveContainers(player);

        if(entityManager.find(Player.class, player.getId()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Database contains player, updating...");
            entityManager.merge(player);
        } else {
            entityManager.persist(player);
        }

        transaction.commit();
        entityManager.close();
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the code where you are trying to initialize the `EntityManager`? It helps if you could give more details about your deployment.

Comment: Hey! @MauricioBuffon, Thanks for your reply! i've updated the OP to contain the instantiating function/method.